# How to restrict user login based on location latitude longitude

Tags: java, android, gps, android-geofence

I am developing a attendence app. It logs in user when user reaches in office else it shows a message "not in office". So for this i need to get users location and need to check whether its between office longitude latitude values. the user can login only if the user is in between that longitude latitude values of office. How to develop this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting location of user, you just can check the distance from origin points that is your office (lat,Lon) if user fall within range you have mention just mark it.

```
float[] results = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(currentlatitude, currentlongitude, originLat, originLon, results);
float distanceInMeters = results[0];
boolean isWithinRange = distanceInMeters < 3000; 

if (isWithinRange) {
    //write your code what ever you wanna perform
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a geofence which will be defined by office area (follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) to figure out how to do that )  For example, to populate a list object named mGeofenceList:

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
    // geofence.
    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

    .setCircularRegion(
            entry.getValue().latitude,
            entry.getValue().longitude,
            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
    )
    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .build());
```

Take user's location everytime while login and check if it belongs to that geofence.If inside, let him/her login otherwise say out of area. use this formula to check:

[image]

**Update**
**Formula explanation:**
If you know the radius of a circle and what is it's center, you can get the either point is inside or outside of the circle by that formula. If the distance from the point to center is greater than the radius then its outside, and vice versa.

you can also see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) method if it helps.

Easy!